# Как правильно написать: "утверждаю управляющий "Липецкий" филиал ФГУП" или "утверждаю управляющий "Липецким" филиалом ФГУП"?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Как правильно написать: *утверждаю управляющий "Липецкий" филиал ФГУП* или *утверждаю управляющий "Липецким" филиалом ФГУП* или *утверждаю управляющий филиалом "Липецкий" филиал ФГУП*?

Comment: Официальное наименование организации какое зарегистрировано? _Липецкий филиал ФГУП_ или _филиал "Липецкий" ФГУП_? Самый первый вариант склонения явно ошибочен.

Comment: Вариант *утверждаю управляющ**ий** ”Липецкий“ филиал ФГУП* выглядит как «утверждаю *(кого? что?)* филиал // филиал *(какой?)* управляющий». Так что как минимум слово «управляющий» должно стоять в винительном падеже. Ну а кавычки, думаю, не нужны — это имя собственное без родовой части (типа *Детский сад «Берёзка»*). Это при родовой части собственно название является подчинённой конструкцией, которую приходится выделять.

Comment: Так что “утверждаю управляющего Липецким филиалом ФГУП”.

Comment: официальное наименование " Липецкий" филиал ФГУП...... и в данном случае мне не  надо  утвердить управляющего. Он уже есть)  Это будет в шапке инструкции.

Comment: @Alex_ander ^^^

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из официального названия ( http://www.list-org.com/company/910099 ), в котором применены кавычки:

> Утверждаю:
>
> управляющий "Липецким" филиалом ФГУП "[наименование ФГУП]" [фамилия,
>   инициалы, подпись]